# How do I automatically wrap lines at 80 or 120 characters in Visual Studio for all of my code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need a plug in to run through all of my existing code and create newlines for any lines over 80 or 120 characters, depending on requirements.

The program is a Windows Forms App written in C#

I know there is `Edit->Advanced->Word Wrap` in Visual Studio 2019, but when I click it, nothing happens. Maybe I needed this feature to be enabled before writing the code, but since it is already written, and there are many files, I don't want to edit them all one by one, if I can do it all automatically.

How can I do this, either through VS2019 or through a plugin?

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio. The word wrap works and doesn't need to be active before or after (just an on/off switch). It does not add new line to your code.

Comment: so its like word wrap in notepad, I need something that actually adds new lines. What can I use

Comment: I don't think there is actual tool for that as creating new line is very specific per person for readability purpose. Arbitrary new line placed at specific character position can break the ability to properly compile the code.

Comment: I think you should not do that. As already noted, the length of a line can significantly influence the readability, and the user who wrote the code might have had a reason to wrap it the way it is. These 80 character line limits come from ancient times when this was the width of a screen. It's not relevant any more.

Comment: You can use CodeMaid to format code