How to change line limit from 80 to 120 symbols?
Every time when I paste code, Visual Studio change my lines
// from
p = obs_properties_add_list(streamlink_group_ppts, S_SLQ, T_SLQ, OBS_COMBO_TYPE_LIST, OBS_COMBO_FORMAT_STRING);

// to
p = obs_properties_add_list(streamlink_group_ppts, S_SLQ, T_SLQ,
                        OBS_COMBO_TYPE_LIST,
                        OBS_COMBO_FORMAT_STRING);

Can you provide step by step tutorial what I need to do in order to change line limit from 80 symbols to 120 for Visual Studio Community 2022 (not VS Code)? There is no such option in "all language" or "C/C++" section of settings.
Or how to disable auto line break? Word wrap still disabled.

Look for code formatting Tools-Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Code Style->Formatting and check if for example clang format is on (if it is you need to change the clang format file)

This question is similar to: How can I make Visual Studio wrap lines at 80 characters?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76732725/how-do-i-automatically-wrap-lines-at-80-or-120-characters-in-visual-studio-for-a

@ThomasWeller I don't think any of those Q&As answers the question about how to set the word wrap at 120 instead of 80 in VS2022.

VS2022 uses ClangFormat by default. Unless you've turned that off, then in the directory where you keep your projects, create a .clang-format file. In that file, put the line:
ColumnLimit: 120

More info about VS2022 and formatting: Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Formatting which contains info such as:

By default, Visual Studio runs clang-format.exe in the background and applies formatting as you type. You can also specify to run it only for manually invoked formatting commands Format Document (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) or Format Selection (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F).

You can also dump all settings to create your .clang-format file. Here's an example using the cmd.exe (I don't know PowerShell):
clang-format --dump-config > .clang-format

Then edit .clang-format and change ColumnLimit.

If the OP (or other person reading this question) has customized Visual Studio’s C++ formatting options, and then creates a .clangformat file, what will be the effect on how those options are applied when formatting?

@Sneftel only the options used by clang-format.exe is affected by this and if OP has indeed created a .clang-format file before, then clang-format --dump-config > .clang-format would just read and dump that configuration to the file.

No, not the ClangFormat options — the options to Visual Studio’s native formatting system.

They are unaffected. As it is by default using clang-format with the default options, this will only affect that. If automatic formatting with clang-formathas been turned off, well, then this won't  have any effect. It must then be turned back on for this to have an effect.
